# How to let Mesh Deform modifier work as expected

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I wanna use the Mesh Deform midifier. I created an own cage mesh and set the modifier, but it seems not working. I don't know what the problem is.

There is a pic:[image: PIC]

The cage: http://speedy.sh/xaajq/alice-cage-mesh.obj

Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you upload the .blend files on pasteall.org?

Comment: Of course, here is the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27383

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For very rough cage, especially when using larger cage to control smaller target mesh, you need to set a higher value for *Precision*.

So, two ways to solve this:

- Try to scale down the cage object;
- Try to set a higher *Precision* value in the Mesh Deform modifier panel. (**`5`** might be relatively appropriate for this particular case)

**Note:**

- Normals on cage mesh are used to determine the inside/outside of the cage, so make sure they are pointing outside. Flip them if not.
- The cage mesh has to be a closed mesh (manifold) to work well. When in **Vertex** or **Edge** selction mode, You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to find the non-manifold edges.

Comment: I tried the two way, but not work. :(

Comment: Well, I tried, they both work. I wonder if you flip the normals of the cage?

Comment: So, I flipped the normals, and it worked. Thank You!